# backbone view this.$ is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, view

I am following a backbone.js [tutorial](http://blog.andyet.com/2010/oct/29/building-a-single-page-app-with-backbonejs-undersc/) and a part of the code isn't working, maybe because Backbone has changed in the meantime or because I'm doing something wrong. This is the render function of my view.

```
// grab and populate our main template
render: function () {
    // once again this is using ICanHaz.js, but you can use whatever
    this.el = ich.app(this.model.toJSON());

    // store a reference to our movie list
    this.movieList = this.$('#movieList');

    return this;
},
```

The element gets appended into the document later in the code. Subsequently, when the code tries to adds elements to `this.movieList`, Javascript says it's undefined.

I have tried changing `this.el = ...` to

```
this.setElement(ich.app(this.model.toJSON()));
```

and that helps because `this.$el` is now defined, but if i try `this.$el.find(...)` it never finds anything, even though through inspection in Chrome it does appear to contain the HTML elements.

Comment: Looks like to use ich.app you should have an script template element with id "app" available on DOM. make sure what `console.log($('#app'))` and `console.log(ich.app(this.model.toJSON()))` resolves to. That can give more insights on what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used ICanHaz but it it works like the other template languages probably returns HTML code. In that case i'd do something like:

```
render: function(){
    this.$el.html(ich.app(this.model.toJSON()));
}
addMovie: function (movie) {
    var view = new MovieView({model: movie});
    this.$el.find("#movieList").append(view.render().el);
},
```

Hope this helps

**PS:** This is the first time I see `this.$('something')` in a backbone code o_O. Is he storing the reference of JQuery on the view?

Comment: `this.$el.find("#movieList")` and `this.$("#movieList")` does the same thing. It's just a shorthand and it's been in Backbone for quite some time, not very well documented though. See [http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar)

Comment: Excellent thanks, that seems to work now. Note the correct code is `this.$el.html(...)` not `this.el.html(...)` as suggested above.